# Disable The Slicer Selection In The PowerBI Embedded Report Using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

I have embedded the PowerBI report using the ReactJS. There is one slicer/dropdown in it. I want to disable that slicer/dropdown programmatically in the ReactJS.

This is my code to get that visual.

```
window.report.getPages().then(pages => {
    pages[0].getVisuals().then(visuals => {
      const clientSlicerVisual = visuals.find(visual => visual.name === "123456789");
    });
});
```

I have tried the below way from the internet to disable the slicer. But it's not working.

```
clientSlicerVisual.setSlicerState({ filters: [] });
```

Any other ways to disable the slicer programatically?

Answer (score 0):

Visuals don't have a "disabled" state, but you can simply [remove the visual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/remove-visual) using the embedded authoring API.